# Cannot start and re-register ECS container in Task Definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have AWS ECS Container service configured along with ALB. After I configured, committed and restarted Nginx, I cannot start or re-register the Nginx container back to ECS Task Definitions or Service.

Comment: Can you show the logs and task definition from Ecs platform?

Comment: @juliansalas, I just realized that ECS containers are dropped after restart because I have Auto Scaling Groups setup in ECS. I should have make changes before creating any task definitions for nginx. Thanks for your response though. I appreciate your time.